# parsing error on xml node with attributes php

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework2

hi I am parsing xml using zendframework2 xml reader   and for some reason there is a small issue..

if I have a node

```
<langstring>value</langstring>
```

this works fine

but if i have a node

```
<langstring xml:lang="x-none" >value</langstring>
```

then the value doesnt get parsed.
Iam not sure what is happening here. Can someone please help.

Cheers
Sonny

Comment: Can you at elast paste some code you are using..?

Answer (score 0):

Try [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
<?php

$XML=<<<XML
<langstring xml:lang="x-none" >value</langstring>
XML;

$XMLObject=new SimpleXMLElement($XML);
print $XMLObject[0];
```